# In Rayman 2: The Great Escape, why doesn't the Fourth Mask of Polokus have a Guardian?

Tags: video-games

When I say the Fourth Mask of Polokus does not have a guardian, I mean the non-PlayStation 2 versions (in Rayman Revolution, there is a guardian: Grolem 13) (Rayman Revolution on the PS2 is essentially a director's cut of three of the previous editions: N64, PC, and DC) (at the opposite, Rayman 2 on the PS1 is somewhat a demo). Maybe the Guardian was killed by the pirates offscreen?

Comment: https://raymanpc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=1032&start=6540 - Others chatting about it.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about my childhood.